# MongoDB show not all elements in subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have the document of the following structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50b8f881065f90c025000014"),
  "education" : {
    "schoolCountry" : 4,
    "schoolTown" : -1,
    "uniCountry" : 4,
    "uniTown" : -1
  },
  "info" : {
    "ava" : "auto.jpg",
    "birthday" : ISODate("1942-04-01T21:00:00Z"),
    "email" : "mail@gmail.com",
    "name" : "name",
    "sex" : 1,
    "surname" : "surname"
  }
}
```

I am trying to output only surname and name

The only thing I was able to achieve is this:

```
db.COLL.find({ }, {
   "_id" : 0,
   "education" : 0,
   "info" : 1
})
```

My idea to show only elements that I need from subdocument failed:

```
db.COLL.find({ }, {
   "_id" : 0,
   "education" : 0,
   "info.surname" : 1,
   "info.name" : 1,
})
```

But hidding (info.email : 0) works. Is it possible to achieve my goal without hidding all unneeded fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix including and excluding fields, aside from turning off `_id` (which is included by default).

So just request the `info.surname` and `info.name` fields:

```
db.coll.find({ }, {
    "_id" : 0,
    "info.surname" : 1,
    "info.name" : 1,
})
```

Sample output:

```
{ "info" : { "name" : "name", "surname" : "surname" } }
```